# Why is my react mapped array flashing and then disappearing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i am retrieving an array of objects containing my firestore storage file information using the function below

```
export const listFiles = async () => {
  const listRef = ref(storage, "/");
  const files: any = [];
  await listAll(listRef)
    .then((res) => {
      res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
        getMetadata(itemRef).then((metadata) => {
          files.push({
            name: metadata.fullPath,
            created: metadata.timeCreated,
          });
        });
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));

  return files;
};
```

in my react front end i call the function the firestore function and set a files state variable equal to the result of the function using code below

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState<any | any>(null);
...
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
      const filesList: any = await listFiles();
      setFiles(filesList)
    };
    fetch();
  }, []);
```

i then map over the returned array in the code below (using chakra ui components btw)

```
<Box textAlign="center">
        {files && (
          <>
            <Text fontSize="3xl">Uploaded Files</Text>
            {files.map((file: any) => {
              return (
                <Box
                  display="flex"
                  alignItems="center"
                  key={file.name}
                  bg="gray.200"
                  m={5}
                  borderRadius="lg"
                  p="2"
                  justifyContent="space-between"
                >
                  <Box textAlign="initial">
                    <Text>{file.name}</Text>
                    <Text>{file.created}</Text>
                  </Box>
                  <Button>
                    <BsCloudDownload />
                  </Button>
                </Box>
              );
            })}
          </>
        )}
      </Box>
```

any ideas why my content appears for a second and then disappears? i've seen others with similar issues in other posts, but have not been able to fix with any solutions i've seen. probably a dumb mistake somewhere, let me know

thanks again

EDIT:
i removed try catch from my firestore query.. let me know if this looks right?

```
export const listTheFiles = async () => {
  const listRef = ref(storage);
  const files: any = [];
  const response = await listAll(listRef);
  response.items.forEach(async (itemRef) => {
    const metadata = await getMetadata(itemRef);
    files.push({ name: metadata.fullPath, created: metadata.timeCreated });
  });
  console.log(files);
  return files;
};
```

Comment: Hint: If you add a `console.log(files)` just before `return files;` from your `listFiles` method - what will be the log? Rewrite your `listFiles` method so it have 0 .then or .catch, because currently your result List will be [empty]. And even if it is populated later - react will not notice that after `setFiles(filesList)` because reference to the array object is not changed, even if array is mutated.

Comment: the console.log returns the array containing my file objects.. figuring out how to rewrite without then catch

Comment: Ok, just to clear that area - `console.log(JSON.stringify(files));`

Comment: JSON.stringify(files) returns [] in the console.. can't open doesnt look like anything is in it

Comment: it is just browser reflected changes of the array after array was logged, but at the point before return your array is empty due to in your method you are not caring about all the promises. Try to get rid of .then.catches and update your question, your 
 function should be completely ok after that

Comment: You have used both `await` and `then` block. Just use one of them ( at `listAll(listRef)` )

Comment: i updated code to remove .thens.. see above and let me know. the console.log(files) of that new function still returns same thing .. array with my objects

Comment: I knew you will try the foreach with async, they do not work nice together :) But it is a very common mistake. for loop will work, array.forEach - will not. I added an answer with info about how it should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to promises inside `listFiles` function are not handled correctly, so `files` were returned as empty array, even if this array will be populated in future - react will not detect that and will not rerender the component. Also, it is a bad practice to mix `async` with .then.catch promises api.

Fixed method:

```
export const listFiles = async () => {
  const listRef = ref(storage, "/");
  const listAllResult = await listAll(listRef);

  const promises = listAllResult.items.map(async (itemRef) => {
    const metadata = await getMetadata(itemRef);
    return {
      name: metadata.fullPath,
      created: metadata.timeCreated
    };
  });

  return Promise.all(promises);
};
```

Sorry, i cant test it at this moment but if you encounter any issues after that - feel free to comment me and i'll update the answer.

Comment: just saw this after i refreshed.. checking it out now

Comment: looks to be fixed.. you're a wizard. i'm still trying to wrap my head around promises and all that. thanks again